# non-root users unable to send mail from command line using exim

Tags: exim

Using Exim - root user can send email from command line, but non root users can not.

```
$ mail -s "test" test@test.com </dev/null
Null message body; hope that's ok
[xxx@master1 /usr/home/xxx]$ 2015-03-31 17:06:34 [58856] 
cwd=/usr/home/xxx 3 args: send-mail -i test@test.com
```

Seeing this in /var/log/messages:

```
Mar 31 17:07:11 master1 exim[59400]: 2015-03-31 17:07:11 [59400] 1Ycxl1-000FS4-0T failed to write to main log: length=134 result=-1 errno=9 (Bad file descriptor)
Mar 31 17:07:11 master1 exim[59400]: write failed on panic log: length=125 result=-1 errno=9 (Bad file descriptor)
Mar 31 17:07:11 master1 exim[59409]: 2015-03-31 17:07:11 [59409] 1Ycxl1-000FSD-1F failed to write to main log: length=134 result=-1 errno=9 (Bad file descriptor)
Mar 31 17:07:11 master1 exim[59409]: write failed on panic log: length=125 result=-1 errno=9 (Bad file descriptor)
```

exim is a symlink - both symlink and actual binary permissions look like:

```
[xxx@master1 ~]$ ls -l `which exim`
lrwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  13 Aug  5  2013 /usr/local/sbin/exim -> exim-4.80.1-2
[xxx@master1 ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/sbin/exim-4.80.1-2
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  983184 Aug  5  2013 /usr/local/sbin/exim-4.80.1-2
```

Have tried adding user xxx as trusted_users in exim config - made no difference

Comment: What is your operating system/ distribution, please? And are you using your distribution's binary package, or not? And if not, why not? Ok, answering my own question - `/usr/local/sbin` is clearly not a system installation. Use the packaged binary, and your problems will likely go away.

Comment: For all we know, the question lacking this information, this could be FreeBSD, Faheem Mitha.  (Certainly `wheel` and `/usr/home` hint at this.)  On FreeBSD, _that is_ where the packaged binary lives.

Comment: Indeed - it is FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE-p4, and that is the distributions binary package

Comment: Are you sure `mail` is invoking /usr/local/sbin/exim and not perhaps an old version in /usr/lib/sendmail or /usr/sbin/sendmail?

Comment: @wurtel I actually intend to use mutt. When I run mutt, I can see it invokes `sendmail -oem -oi`, and immediately thereafter I see the exim message in /var/log/messages. (`/usr/sbin/sendmail -> /usr/sbin/mailwrapper`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Others](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=41655) have suggested to resolve this with

```
chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/exim
```

In this case both mail and mutt is invoking sendmail.

Problem resolved with:

```
chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Now messages are sent successfully, and /var/log/exim/mainlog is written to and reflect as such.

Comment: So you have `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and `/usr/local/sbin/exim-4.80.1-2`? So are you even running `exim` now to deliver your messages?

Comment: @roaima sorry for the noob question - but how do I tell? I assumed exim because of:

1- The fact that immediately after running a program like mail and mutt, exim writes to /var/log/messages
2- When root runs mutt/mail, messages are appended in /var/log/exim/mainlog, and 3 `sudo ps aux | egrep 'exim|sendmail'` yields only `/usr/local/sbin/exim -bd -q30m (exim-4.80.1-2)`

Comment: What is result of `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail`?

Comment: A lot of this confusion in various comments is coming from the fact that people aren't aware of how this stuff works on FreeBSD.  **It is not like Linux operating systems.**  The BSDs use [mailwrapper](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mailwrapper). And [third-party stuff from ports goes in `/usr/local`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier).

Comment: @roaima to answer your question, as @JdeBP pointed out, `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is a symlink to `/usr/sbin/mailwrapper`. Initially I tried to chmod only the symlink with `chmod -h`, but in the end the plain chmod did the trick by updating the permissions of `/usr/sbin/mailwrapper`

Comment: @Vuade I missed the OS description because it was buried in the comments. This is why people are asked to update their Questions with pertinent information.

Comment: after so much pain this is the answer that fixed it for me -- crazy that no where else on the internet mentions this as a possible solution -- my error was `ssmtp: Cannot open mailhub:25` -- when trying to send mail through any various means mailx mutt sstmp. I knew there was a permission error but didn't know where.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this showed up on Google.

My solution was as simple as calling `/usr/sbin/sendmail` instead of just `sendmail`.

Found the path using `which sendmail` (as root). No permission change was needed.

(I use `nullmailer`'s `sendmail` 'decoy', not even `exim`; don't think it makes a difference though)